# Cloning display output via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, display

Is it possible to clone image from display via ssh? I want to see what is on my first laptop display from another laptop, but without any additional software like teamviewer or vnc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: Yes, but you may be unhappy with the results.

The protocol you are looking for is called [X11 Forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine). This option must be enabled on your server by setting `X11Forwarding yes` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, then reloading the daemon.

Once enabled on the server, the client must initiate their ssh session using the `-x` flag.

The major limitations of this technology are that:

- The data is not optimized for transfer over the wire. For most environments you end up with a low framerate and/or graphical artifacts. As long as you're doing something like running a GUI installer it should not be a problem, but do not expect to be able to stream video / play a game using X11 forwarding.
- The client must have an X server installed. If you are connecting from a Windows machine (or another machine that does not have an X server installed), you may need to use a project such as [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) in order to actually interpret the data once you get it to the client.